# eBay Product API getProductDetails - Product ID value xxxx is not valid for product ID type UPC

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

Attempting to get EPID for products in eBay Motors Parts & Accessories catalog by submitting UPC.

Here is the code for the call:

```
$appID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$siteID  = 'EBAY-MOTOR';                            // siteID needed in request
$verb    = 'getProductDetails';                  // the call being made:
$version = '1.4.0';                          // eBay API version

///Build the request XML request which is first part of multi-part POST
$xmlReq = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n";
$xmlReq .= '<' . $verb . 'Request xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/marketplacecatalog/v1/services">' . "\n";
$xmlReq .= "<productDetailsRequest>\n";
$xmlReq .= "<dataset>DisplayableProductDetails</dataset>\n";
$xmlReq .= "<productIdentifier><UPC>" . $upc . "</UPC></productIdentifier>\n";
$xmlReq .= "</productDetailsRequest>\n";
$xmlReq .= "</" . $verb . "Request>";

// Create a new eBay session (defined below) 
$session = new eBaySession_Product($appID, $version, $siteID, $verb);

$respXmlStr = $session->sendHttpRequest($xmlReq);   // send multi-part request and get string XML response
print "respXmlStr: $respXmlStr\n";

if(stristr($respXmlStr, 'HTTP 404') || $respXmlStr == '')
    die('<P>Error sending request');

$respXmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($respXmlStr);     // create SimpleXML object from string for easier parsing
```

Here is the response:

```
Outcome: Failure
ePID:
Error Id: 18
Error Domain: Marketplace
Error Severity: Error
Error Category: System
Error Message: Product ID value 841380031426 is not valid for product ID type UPC.
Error Subdomain: MarketplaceCatalog
Version: 1.3.1
Timestamp: 2017-03-29T16:13:43.672Z
```

The call works for products that are not in the Parts & Accessories catalog , e.g. a Harry Potter book but I can't get it to work for any of the auto parts UPC codes. I know that 841380031426 is a valid UPC so I'm stumped. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jay

P.S. Already tried the Product-findProducts, Shopping->FindProducts and Finding->findItemsByProduct calls with no success.

Comment: If anyone can provide a working product identifier for this API call that is not an ePID I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

UPC isn't a Harry Potter book upcitemdb.com/upc/841380031426

If 841380031426 is the ProductID use

```
$xmlReq .= "<productIdentifier><productid>" . $upc . "</productid></productIdentifier>\n";
```

docu is here: 
https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/product/CallRef/types/ProductIdentifier.html

---

One more error:

```
$siteID  = 'EBAY-MOTOR';
```

An Harry Potter Book won't be at ebay motors

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.